# GSP date parsing error while trying to auto-populate a date into textfield

Tags: grails

I am trying to auto populate a textfield on a GSP template with a parsed date as:

```
<label>Date of birth(mm-dd-yyyy):</label>&nbsp<g:textField name="dateOfBirth" style ="border-radius: 5px" 
                    value="${Date.parse('dd-MM-yyyy', recordToEdit.dateOfBirth)}"></g:textField><br>
```

and I get this:

```
| Error 2014-08-13 14:26:18,960 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ParseException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0/customer/displayRecordDetails - parameters:
secondaryId: 1
uniqueId: 903123A
Unparseable date: "Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 UTC 1972". Stacktrace follows:
Message: Unparseable date: "Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 UTC 1972"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your format `'dd-MM-yyyy'` does not correspond to the string you want to parse
should be

```
Date.parse( 'EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy', 'Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 UTC 1972' )
```

then you can format it:

```
Date.parse( 'EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy', 'Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 UTC 1972' ).format( 'dd-MM-yyy' )
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I null safe against a dateOfBirth possibly being null in this G-String? value="${Date.parse( 'EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy', recordToEdit.dateOfBirth)?.format( 'dd-MM-yyy' )}" didn't work for me.

Comment: `value="${recordToEdit.dateOfBirth ? Date.parse( 'EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy', recordToEdit.dateOfBirth).format( 'dd-MM-yyy' ) : ''}"`